# Snow Leopard, sqlite3-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, osx-snow-leopard

So I followed every suggestion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350359/snow-leopard-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-issue)

without success.  I'm running os x 10.6, rails 2.3.3, ruby 1.9.1 and still getting this error when I try accessing the front page of my rails app:

uninitialized constant SQLite3::Driver::Native::Driver::API

I've googled every possible combination of snow leopard, rails, sqlite3 without any luck.  Hoping someone can help.  Thanks!

Comment: why is this being voted to close?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved this by recompiling ruby 1.9.1 with the appropriate sqlite3 libraries linked.  So in my case I needed to create this link:

```
sudo ln -s  /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, simply

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work for me since I was still running with ruby 1.9.1 32 bit

Comment: This didn't work for me either. I'm still on Ruby 1.8.7 though. I had to reinstall XCode then recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

Weird, but I uninstalled all my Sqlite3 versions and resintalled Sqlite3 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

ennuikillers' answer worked for me. I'll add that I did this on a mac (running snow leopard) and  /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib already existed and was symlinked to the wrong thing.

I had to add the line: 
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

before the symlink line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing happen on an older Ubuntu server (6.06), on which I had installed SQLite from source. There was no ld.so.conf file so I had to create that and add /usr/local/lib to it.