# SQLite3 problem since Rails 2.3.5 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite

I was running Rails 2.3.4 with SQLite3 on a Snow Leopard box without any problems. I've just done a pull on a new project that requires 2.3.5 so I did a sudo gem update to get the latest version of Rails. This installed fine but when I ran rake db:migrate I got the following error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SQLite3::Driver::Native::Driver::API
```

I've tried re-installing the sqlite3 gem (via: sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby) but am still getting the same error...

I have XCode 3.2 (and everything was working before the 2.3.5 update)

Any help would be appreciated as I'm at a loss as to how to fix this!

-Ash

Edit: This is the output when I run the install on sqlite3-ruby:

```
$ sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5...

No definition for _wrap_new_CallbackData

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc_set

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc_get

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc2_set

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc2_get

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_data_set

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_data_get

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_libversion

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_close

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_changes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_total_changes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_interrupt

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_complete

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_complete16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_busy_handler

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_busy_timeout

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_set_authorizer

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_trace

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_open

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_open16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_errcode

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_errmsg

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_errmsg16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_prepare

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_prepare16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_null

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_parameter_name

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_parameter_index

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_name

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_name16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_decltype

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_decltype16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_step

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_data_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_bytes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_bytes16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_type

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_finalize

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_reset

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_create_function

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_create_function16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_aggregate_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_bytes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_bytes16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16le

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16be

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_type

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_error

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_error16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16le

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16be

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_value

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_aggregate_context
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5...

No definition for _wrap_new_CallbackData

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc_set

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc_get

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc2_set

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_proc2_get

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_data_set

No definition for _wrap_CallbackData_data_get

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_libversion

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_close

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_changes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_total_changes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_interrupt

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_complete

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_complete16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_busy_handler

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_busy_timeout

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_set_authorizer

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_trace

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_open

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_open16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_errcode

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_errmsg

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_errmsg16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_prepare

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_prepare16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_null

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_parameter_name

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_bind_parameter_index

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_name

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_name16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_decltype

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_decltype16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_step

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_data_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_bytes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_bytes16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_column_type

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_finalize

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_reset

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_create_function

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_create_function16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_aggregate_count

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_bytes

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_bytes16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16le

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_text16be

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_value_type

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_blob

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_double

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_error

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_error16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_int

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_int64

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16le

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_text16be

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_result_value

No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_aggregate_context
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350359/snow-leopard-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-issue my recommendation would be to install rvm, its much better anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out! I had built my copy of Ruby from source under Leopard and hadn't rebuilt it since upgrading. Not entirely sure why it would work with 2.3.4 but not with 2.3.5 - something must have changed.

I just changed my path from the custom build to the copy that ships with Snow Leopard, re-ran the gem updates and all was good again!