# Why can't I get sqlite installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I go to install using "sudo bundle install" to install all of them...it throws an error on sqlite3:

```
 Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

            /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


    Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `build_extensions'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in `install'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/bin/bundle:13
        from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Then I think maybe I have it already installed because i've used it before...but when I do "rake db:create" it gives me this:

Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what system? From your paths it looks like MacOS X. Have you installed the developer tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have XCode installed. The necessary header files should be installed by that.

Also, unrelated advice, stop using sudo. Look into [installing RVM](https://rvm.io). It will make your life easier.

Related question: [Snow Leopard & Ruby on Rails - SQLite3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350359/snow-leopard-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-issue)

Comment: Also worth checking out is [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) and [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) to manage dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the sqlite3.dll file. Go to the bin folder in your ruby folder and look for a sqlite3.dll file. If you can't find it there then download it for http://www.sqlite.org/download.html. Then put the dll file in your bin(ruby's bin) folder and run bundle install again and see if that works.